# iBook G3 freezes, no touchpad or button response

Tags: macos, display, ibook

I have an iBook G3 (900 MHz).

When on battery and the display goes to sleep I cannot wake it up. OS X is not sleeping as I can hear the hard drive running and `Ctrl + Command + Power` does get the restart sound and it does restart.

Connecting power does not help once the display sleeps and refuses to wake. I do not notice this issue when on AC power and the display sleeps.

I don't know much about Mac notebooks or OS X. Is there some trick to wake the display?

I'm running Tiger with all updates.

---

It finally froze up while the screen was active, so its not a wake issue but possibly something else?, the touchpad and buttons do not respond which explains why it cannot wake the screen.

Any logs I can check that might help?

Ran hardware diagnostics and everything passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a faulty PMU (Power Management Unit). Try restarting the iBook holding down Shift, CTRL, Option and Power keys to reset the PMU. Logic board failures on the G3 had issues with sleeping iBooks also.

Comment: check my edit, new information

Comment: After much diagnosis, you are correct, it is the logic board, time to sell it for parts!